# exported typed functions that return functions should NOT require the returned function to be typed to work in other modules

Tags: flowtype

For example if you are using `redux-actions` and have created the following module definition for it:

```
declare module 'redux-actions' {
  declare type ActionType = string

  declare type Action = {
    type: ActionType,
    payload?: any,
    error?: bool,
    meta?: any,
  }

  declare function createAction<T>(
    type: string,
    payloadCreator?: (...args: Array<T>) => any,
    metaCreator?: Function
  ): (...args: Array<T>) => Action
}
```

and then you use that function to return a new function like this:

```
export const selectProfileTab = createAction('SELECT_PROFILE_TAB', (index: number) => {
  playSound()
  return { index }
})
```

and then in another file use it incorrectly like this:

`selectorProfileTab('someString')`

that won't report an error. It seems to be because flow requires annotations at the "boundaries" of modules. Am I correct?

Because the following does work:

```
export const selectProfileTab: (index: number) => any = createAction('SELECT_PROFILE_TAB', (index: number) => {
  playSound()
  return { index }
})
```

Notice I've annotated the returned function. The following will now produce an error:

`selectProfileTab('someString')`

I'm just trying to get a hold of this and verify this because it's a lot of extra "boilerplate" to annotate those returned functions, especially when it calling `selectProfileTab('someString')` would correctly produce an error if used in the same file. It makes you think: what's the point in creating module definitions for the `redux-actions` package which doesn't have them yet if it doesn't provide any/much value since you have to annotate your returned functions anyway. That's quite disappointing. Am I correct in determining that it's a module "boundaries" limitation/requirement with Flow? Are there any ways to get the desired result of not having to type returned functions that you export?